# I tried to update to 22.04 and my dual boot machine gets stuck on splash screen

Tags: boot, upgrade, kubuntu, 22.04

CPU: Intel i5 2nd gen

RAM: 2x4GB

HDD: 2 x 500 GB (one drive has Windows 10, the other Kubuntu)

GPU: AMD Cedar card

This is a Dell Optiplex 390, with an extra HDD and stick of RAM.

I can boot into Windows 10. When I try to boot into Kubuntu, I get stuck on the black screen with a logo, and loading wheel, which freezes, but I can move the mouse.

IDK if Ubuntu updated correctly (only upgraded Linux versions once, and it was on a Ubuntu Cinnamon system), and I had to try a few things to update (tried to see which packages were being changed, and then tried to close that Konsole window, (becuz I had opened another window to try again and had been mentioned something about a lock on the file, because you couldn't type anymore in the old window, but had to close it)). Something might have messed up because I was tired, but who knows.

I thought it upgraded correctly, and I told it to restart as needed. I tried booting into recovery mode and can boot to there. I haven't ran any memory testing since the upgrade. It worked fine before I upgraded to 22.04.

Please help, thanks. I'm tech savvy, but IDK what to do.

I've already tried power cycling it.

Comment: Looks like a video issue since you can boot into recovery mode.  From recovery, try installing any proprietary drivers for your AMD card. Don't have AMD cards myself, so cannot be more specific.

Comment: Do I need separate sets for Linux or Windows, or can I just upgrade them on the Windows side? How do I upgrade drivers? I'm newer to Linux than Windows, and don't know what to do.

Comment: It has the spinning wheel spin for a bit, before freezing.

Comment: The Windows drivers are separate from the LInux ones.  you may upgrade drivers through the Software and Updates app/Additional Drivers tab   or in a terminal run ubuntu-drivers.

Comment: I might have been able to boot into 22 once, and changed the background, before this whole issue.

Comment: I tried booting into Kubuntu after pulling the GPU (running integrated graphics). It still froze. I also added an extra HDD, which I'd need to wipe (because of where I got it from). My next idea is to boot into Windows 10 and rescue my files that way (if I can becuz of tech issues), before clean installing Kubuntu on a drive and updating drivers. I don't know how to update the drivers in recovery mode.

Comment: Got some more ideas on Ubuntu forums, haven't tested them yet, because of how busy I am. Can someone explain nomodeset?

Comment: nomodeset gets added to the grub command line starting with "linux", towards the end where the words "quiet splash" occur.  For a one time boot, you may just edit in the word when booting grub (type E to edit, then ctrl-X to boot (instructions at bottom of screen). Permanent addition is made by editing the /etc/default/grub file and adding the nomodeset to the "quiet splash" words on the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line, then running sudo update-grub.

Comment: @ubfan1 , should I give nomodeset a try, at some point (because I'm tired now, and won't likely have time for a while)?

Comment: The nomodeset is easy to try from the grub menu.  Also, ensure things are up to date with a sudo apt update, then sudo apt upgrade .  Anything interrupting an upgrade might have left things in a state that could not create the video module. It might help to list all the nvidia packages (dpkg -l |grep -i nvidia ) then sudo apt purge pkgnames and start fresh with the sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall or the Software and Updates/additional drivers.

Comment: I'll try those tips I've picked up from you guys at some point, when I have the time. What do you mean by grub command line? I'm not real comfortable with the command line, but I'll give it a try from the recovery mode root prompt.

Comment: On the grub menu screen, at the bottom are instructions, type e to edit, etc.  Type e, then use the arrow keys to get to the line starting with "linux", and move to the "splash quiet" words, type in nomodeset, then control x to boot. An easy  quick one time change.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know what to do when I finally try it.